# How do I create an archive page as a <table> including metadata?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, meta-value

I'm really struggling getting this seemingly simple thing to work. I have a list of "vendors" as a CPT. They have metadata like "contact name" and "last invoice date". I'd like to have the "archive" page for these vendors show a simple table:

| Name | Contact name | Last Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe's Plumbing | Joe Anderson | March 31, 2021 |

I can not seem to figure out how to get metadata into this. I'm also struggling with getting Wordpress to stop inserting `<h2>`s, but at least I can style around that!

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header", "tagName":"header"} /-->

<section class="wp-block-query inner-width content">
    <table>
    <!-- wp:query {"query":{"perPage":1000,"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"vendor","categoryIds":[],"tagIds":[],"order":"asc","orderBy":"title","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":true},"tagName":"main","align":"wide","layout":{"inherit":false}} -->
        
        <!-- wp:post-template {"align":"wide"} -->
        <tr>
            <td><!-- wp:post-title {"isLink":true} /--></td>
            <td>Contact</td>
            <td>Last Invoice Date</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /wp:post-template -->
    <!-- /wp:query -->
    </table>
</section>

<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"footer", "tagName":"footer"} /-→
```

How can I make `<td>Contact</td>` the actual contact's name (meta data name `contact`)? I've seen other solutions using PHP, but when I do that on the HTML page it doesn't work. Maybe I followed the wrong guide?

Comment: do you have a link to the guide you followed? This is the first time I've seen somebody try to do this, you may need to create custom blocks to do this, though if you do then you can use PHP to render/display the block. Is this a block based theme or is it a template in the database?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/create-block-theme/ is the guide I followed. I've then been diving into other themes to try and create this page. I genuinely thought this would be fairly simple; any guidance on next steps is appreciated!